# Looping through an Array of objects in Javascript sent by socket.emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I am making a blockchain in Node.js and am trying to print generated blocks in html. I am using socket. io to emit data to html, but am having issues with sending an object array of blocks that are in the blockchain.

So far my code looks like this:

**Client.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
const port = myArgs[0];
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

class Block {
    constructor(index, timestamp, data, previousHash) {
        this.index = index;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.data = data;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.hash = this.generateHash();
    }
    generateHash() {
        return SHA256(this.index + this.timestamp + this.previousHash + JSON.stringify(this.data)).toString();
    }
}

class Blockchain {
    constructor() {
        this.blockchain = [this.createGenesisBlock()];
    }

    createGenesisBlock() {
        return new Block(0, Date.now(), "prvi blok verige", "0");
    }

    getTheLatestBlock() {
        return this.blockchain[this.blockchain.length - 1];
    }

    addNewBlock(newBlock) {
        newBlock.previousHash = this.getTheLatestBlock().hash;
        newBlock.hash = newBlock.generateHash();
        this.blockchain.push(newBlock);
    }

    validateBlock(newBlock) {
        const latestBlock = this.getTheLatestBlock();
        if (newBlock.previousHash !== latestBlock.hash)
            return false;
        if (newBlock.index <= latestBlock.index)
            return false;
        if (newBlock.hash !== newBlock.generateHash())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    validateChain() {
        for (let i = 1; i < this.blockchain.length; i++) {
            const currentBlock = this.blockchain[i];
            const previousBlock = this.blockchain[i - 1];
            if (currentBlock.hash !== currentBlock.generateHash()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (currentBlock.previousHash !== previousBlock.hash) {
                return false;
            }
            if (currentBlock.index <= previousBlock.index)
                return false;
            return true;

        }
    }
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('GUI connected on port: ' + port);
    socket.emit('onConnection', port);

    let logCoin = new Blockchain();
    console.log("mining logcoin in progress...");
    logCoin.addNewBlock(
        new Block(1, Date.now(),"Block 1")
    );

    logCoin.addNewBlock(
        new Block(2, Date.now(), "Block 2")
    );

    logCoin.addNewBlock(
        new Block(3, Date.now(),"Block 3")
    );
    console.log(logCoin);
    socket.emit('blockLedger', JSON.stringify(logCoin,null));


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("Client has disconnected");
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port + ':');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 3rem;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #contentWrap {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #contentWrap>div {
        flex: 1;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #blocks {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #blocks>li {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    }

    #blocks>li:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #efefef;
    }

    #minedBlocks {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #minedBlocks>li {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    }

    #minedBlocks>li:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #efefef;
    }

    #port {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="element1">
            <h1>Blockchain</h1>
            <p id="connectionStatus">Status: Offline</p>
            <form id="form" action="">
                <button id="mine">Mine</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="element2" style="align-self: center;">
            <form id="form" action="">
                <div id="port">
                    <input id="portInput" autocomplete="off" /><button>Connect port</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrap">
        <div id="ledger">
            <ul id="blocks">
                <li>Blockchain ledger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mined">
            <ul id="minedBlocks">
                <li>Mining...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('onConnection', function (msg) {
            document.getElementById('connectionStatus').innerText = "Status: Online: PORT " + msg;
        });
        socket.on('blockLedger', function (msg) {
            var index;
            var data;
            var timeStamp;
            var previousHash;
            var hash;
            var blocks = document.getElementById('blocks');
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
            obj.forEach(function (arrayItem) {          // here is where i try to loop throught //the array
                let item = document.createElement("li");
                item.textContent = arrayItem.index;
                blocks.appendChild(item);
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            })

        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to add all block indexes to a list, but nothing is added to the list. I dont think the forEach loop even works.

[The array looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgLEi.png)

[And like this when i send it to html stringified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCdSK.png)

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
I used the solution from @ZackNewsham and it works, thanks!

Comment: forEack work on Array, it seems you use forEach on a Object (but I look at yoyr code very quickly)

Comment: @Nick so how can i access the array in that object?

Comment: the object structure seems to be `{ blockchain: [] }` - so when you run `obj = JSON.parse(msg)`, you can access `obj.blockchain.forEach`